# How to use JMSSerializerBundle with Gedmo Timestampable

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I am using [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle) with Symfony3. I am using `TimestampableEntity` trait. What I want to achieve is to receive that trait with `JMSSerializer`.

```
use Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Traits\SoftDeleteableEntity;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;

class Thread
{

    use TimestampableEntity;
    use SoftDeleteableEntity;
    (...)
}
```

I have added metadata to the `jms_serializer` config like this:

config.yml

```
jms_serializer:
    enable_short_alias: false # controls if "serializer" service is aliased to jms_serializer.serializer s
    metadata:
        directories:
            - { path: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/Gedmo/serializer", namespace_prefix: 'Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits' }
```

\app\Reources:

```
Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        created_at:
            expose: true
```

But it is not working.

I know that I can configure it to use my `Thread` class and expose all necessary fields but I wonder if it is possible for traits.

Comment: Yes, it works with traits. Why don't you use annotations instead of yml for configuration ? IMHO I think its more readable in one file instead of having to check 2 files ...

Comment: It is but if I use annotations I need to add getter to each entity which using that trait. I want to add trait and forget about JMSSerializer (it should be done autmatically, just with "use" method). The perfect solution would be to use annotation for entity fields and enable gedmo timestampable by default

Comment: My getters/setters are defined only in the trait, not in the entities which use it. I'm searching for jms documentation with yml files but cant find one.

Comment: @ChuckNorris how to you override timestampable from gedmo in your entity?

Comment: you create a trait in your project : AppBundle\Traits\TimestampableEntity. `trait TimestampableEntity { ... here you define your attributes / getters / setters like in the gedmo timestampable, and you add the jms_serializer annotations ...}`  and then, in your entity : `use TimestampableEntity;`